# Use Conda to install Spark NLP with GPU support?

Tags: tensorflow, pip, anaconda, johnsnowlabs-spark-nlp

The Spark NLP Installation instructions:

https://nlp.johnsnowlabs.com/docs/en/install

have several different methods for installing Spark NLP, in a few different languages. They have instructions for installing it with GPU support, but not for pip/conda. Is there a way to do this? Is it possible to install spark nlp, install TF separately, and point spark nlp to the TF install w/gpu support?